Search Function in JavaScript to retain item and will not disappear upon erasure
I am creating a simple data table where it shows me the values of tracking from a firebase realtime database I am generating the table via JavaScript. Here is my code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Build a table</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.2/firebase-database.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input id="searchbar" 
               onkeyup="search_animal()" 
               type="text" name="search" 
               placeholder="Search item..">

    </div>


    <script>
            // JavaScript code

            function search_animal() {
            let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
            input = input.toLowerCase();
            let x = document.getElementsByClassName('pritem');

            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                else {
                x[i].style.display = "xx";
                }
            }
            }

    </script>




    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }


        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            margin: 20px;
        }

        #searchbar {
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: 50%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #list {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .animals {
            font-size: 1.2em;
            padding: 10px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
            animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }

        .animals:last-child {
            border-bottom: none;
        }

        @keyframes fadeIn {
            from {
                opacity: 0;
                transform: translateY(-10px);
            }

            to {
                opacity: 1;
                transform: translateY(0);
            }
        }        
    </style>

    <button onclick="addData()">CLICK ME</button>

    <style>
        table {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

<table id = "list">

        <tbody id = 'xx'>
            <th width = 200 >Requesting Office</th>
            <th width = 200 >Mayor's Office</th>
            <th width = 200 >Treasury Office</th>
            <th width = 200 >Budget Office</th>
            <th width = 200 >Mayor's Office</th>
        </tbody>
</table>
</body>
<script src="build-table.js"></script>
</html>

For the generation of table here is my code:
  function generateTable(table, data) {
    for (let element of data) {
      let row = table.insertRow();
      
      for (key in element) {
        let cell = row.insertCell();
        row.setAttribute('class', "pritem")
        let text = document.createTextNode(element[key]);
        
        cell.appendChild(text);
      }
    }
  }

I am hauling the files from my realtime database values as follows:
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);  
  var ltbmofiles = firebase.database().ref("prLTBMO");
 
  
  ltbmofiles.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    var placementObjectrValuesSplit = Object.values(snapshot.val())
    valueMax = placementObjectrValuesSplit
    // will show undefined if not defined or not yet present
    for (var x = 0; x <= placementObjectrValuesSplit.length-1; x++) {
        mountains.push(placementObjectrValuesSplit[x]);
        console.log(placementObjectrValuesSplit[x])

    }
    let table = document.querySelector("table");
    // let data = Object.keys(mountains[0]);
    // generateTableHead(table, data);
    generateTable(table, mountains);

})  

My problem with my code is this:

while it shows my search quite properly when I search "treasury" for example, it shows the treasury row searched. However, when you clear the search bar, it does not show the full table again and whenever you search a word it doesn't show anything anything anymore. Any ideas why this happens and how can I fix it?

I tried putting the tag properly from the row, while it shows me the item properly, it disappears.

This is suspiciously similar to this other question. In fact, it's practically identical even down to your interesting use of the word "haul". You're not meant to run with multiple accounts on Stack Overflow

Side Note: <style> is no longer valid inside <body>. It was only valid with the usage of the scope attribute which was deprecated in 2016. The only permitted child elements of html are head and body. script must be placed in either one of them.
